# How to detect if two input elements like text fields are typed in. (php/javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, events, button, input

If two input elements in a form - for example - text fields, lets say username and password, get text input with length > 0, how would you create an event to change a submit button color the moment the user has typed in both fields?

Comment: Please explain more what you exactly trying to do?

Comment: If you have a form, and two input fields, one for username and one for password, and a button. How would you change the submit button color the moment the user starts typing his password after he typed in his username?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        empty = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
        empty += !inputs[i].value;
    }
    if (empty == 0) {
        //write code for changing the button color
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer above, and here is a jquery answer if you like the looks better!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").change(checkFunction());
    $("#password").change(checkFunction());
}
function checkFunction() {
    var user = $("#username").val();
    var pass = $("#password").val();
    if (user && pass) {
        $("#buttonid").css("background-color:#HEXCODE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a javascript function that checks if both inputs have a value greater than zero and if they do it changes the color of the submit button when called.

Use the [onChange](http://w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) attribute in the input tag and place the name of the javascript function in the attribute.

You can also set the attribute by doing

```
Object.onChange = functionToCall();
```

onChange fires the function it's set to whenever the input value changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jquery in your project, you can try something like this:

Assuming your inputs have ids:

```
<input id="username" name="username"/>
<input id="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

You can bind to the keyup event on either input element to change the color of the button:

```
$('#username, #password').keyup(function(){
    if ($.trim($('#username').val()) != '' && $.trim($('#password').val()) != '') {
        $('#submit').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the running fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/NS5z6/**

**HTML:**

```
<input type=text id=username />
<input type=password id=password />
<input type=submit id=submit />
```

**CSS:**

```
#submit{ background-color: red; }
```

**JS:**

```
$('input[id="username"], input[id="password"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val()!="")
  { 
      $("input[id='submit']").css("background-color","green");
  }else{ 
      $("input[id='submit']").css("background-color","red");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following logic

```
<input type = "text" name = "username" class = "text">
   <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "text">
   <input type = "button" class = "button">
   <script>
     $(".text").live("keyup", function(){

       var filled = true; 

       $(".text").each(function(i, v){
          if($(this).val() == ''){
             filled = false
          }
       });

       if(filled){
        $(".button").css("background-color:#black");
       }
     });
   </script>
```